# Swift: protocol with associatedtype with constraint yields "illegal instruction"

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I have code below:

```
protocol Transformable {
    associatedtype OutputType
    func transform() -> OutputType
}

protocol AB {
    associatedtype A: Transformable where A.OutputType == B
    associatedtype B: Transformable where B.OutputType == A
}
```

I got the error:

Command failed due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4

without any more details of what the error is.

The code does feel a bit weird but what is the problem?

Comment: The line `associatedtype A` cannot be evaluated because it needs to evaluate `associatedType B` first in `A.OutputType == B`. B itself needs to evaluate A for the same reason! So basically you're stuck in a cycle, and your code can't compile. You can work around this using `:` instead of `==` but this has its own problems....

Comment: Thanks @PranavKasetti can you let me know what "own problems" are?

Comment: You can Google the error message which comes up.